# Category product positioning not working

Tags: magento2, category-products, position

Category product positioning is not working in one of our webshops running magento 2. Product listing is set on position in admin and the category, and all products have their own position set in category settings, yet product listing in frontend is not changed. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Which Magento 2 version are you using ?

Comment: Check my answer if you help for same.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269372/position-sort-not-working-on-product-listing-page-magento2-2-7/269452#269452