# Position sort not working on product listing page magento2.2.7

Tags: product, magento2.2.7

[image: this is category admin section where I have set products position.]

But not showing correct order on category page.

Answer (score 1):

In default Magento Version 2.2.7 product listing page category product Position working fine.

If you have customized product collection for list page, then you have to need sorting your collection using Position like `addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')`

**Example:**

```
$productCollection = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC');
```